# Offilne Maps with MapBox in Android

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am working on an android application which contains modules like offline maps.I want to download map (data set) of a particular area based on user input then user can select two locations start and destination and i need to draw routes on the map. can any one please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**mapsforge** was built just for that. It is incorporated into many projects.

GitHub: [mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge)

**Mapsforge** gives you full android samples that demonstrates the usage of the offline mapping infrastructure with the usage of their Android libraries.

In addition, the map tiles **are free** and can be downloaded from [here](http://download.mapsforge.org/maps/)